# Find the smallest positive number that when divided by 24 and 16 gives remainder 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am elementary school student and the only thing I can do rn is to go and try it with every possible number, but isn't that too much?

Is there equation for this ?

If it was programming I wouldn't have problem doing it, but I can't write down equation for this.

EDIT: One more thing, the number is 51, but how to get it ?

Comment: Why not just $3$?

Comment: $48k+3$ it's better

Comment: $16,24\mid x\!-\!3\iff {\rm lcm}(16,24)\mid x\!-\!3,\,$ and $\,{\rm lcm}(16,24) = 8\,{\rm lcm}(2,3) = 8(2\cdot 3),\,$ so $\, x = 3 + 48n.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. If a number leaves remainder 3 when divided by 16 and 24 then subtracting 3 by that number should result in another number which is purely divisible by both 16 and 24. Conversely we can say that all common multiples of 16 and 24 when increased by 3 will give numbers which yield a remainder of 3 when divided by 16 and 24. Since we need the smallest such number first let us find the lowest common multiple of 16 and 24:
$$ {L.C.M(16,24) = 48}$$
Now as stated if we add 3 to this number it must yeild the smallest number leaving reminder 3 when divided by both therefore,
$$ 48 + 3 = 51 $$
So $51$ is the answer.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Solved, described, explained :D Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: Except the actual answer to the problem is $3$.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is find the Least Common Multiple of $24$ and $16$, which happens to be $48,$ and then add $3$ to that number. Hence, $LCM(24,16)+3=48+3=51.$

Here is an explanation of why this works:

Let $y$ be the smallest positive number that when divided by $24$ and $16$ gives remainder $3.$ Then there are some positive integers $m$ and $n$ (assuming non-zero, otherwise this problem becomes trivial as others have noted) so that $y=24m+3$ and $y=16n+3$. Then we have that $24m+3=16n+3 \implies24m=16n.$ Therefore, we need $24m=16n$ to be as small as possible. This tells us we just need to find the Least Common Multiple of $24$ and $16.$

This process can be applied in general to any remainder and any two divisors. Let $y$ be smallest positive number that when divided by $a$ and $b$ gives remainder $r.$ Then $y=LCM(a,b)+r$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the simultaneous congruences $x\equiv 3\mod 24$ and $x\equiv 3\mod 16$.

Comment: bit steep for an elementary school student.

Comment: @thesmallprint Do you really think this is an elementary school problem?

Comment: Why does someone down-voted? The solution is right. It's just not fair!

Comment: It is elementary school problem :/ We got testing tommorow (whole country) and this is one of them :/ I am 15 y.o

Comment: @JohnDouma well i don't see any reason to doubt his claim of it being so

Comment: @thesmallprint Fifteen is the age of a high school student, not an elementary school student. Also, if he can write a program to do this then he would easily see the solution before completing the program.

Comment: Well yeah, i am rly good at programming but it's little bit different in math.

Comment: @JohnDouma ah fair enough, sorry, i wasn't aware of the age and how that equates to what kind of school he goes to

Comment: @JohnDouma, to be fair, because I failed a grade, I was still in junior high at 15, and we didn't learn any algebra until then.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand why you won't accept $3$ as the solution. Anyway, you don't need to check every number as you know that it will leave a remainder of $3$ when divided by $24$. So it must be one of
$$3,24+3,2(24)+3,3(24)+3,\dots=3,27,51,75,\dots$$
Trying just $3$ of these gives the solutions $3=0(16)+3$ and $51=3(16)+3$.

Comment: I don't think I understand this, but fine...
I wanted to do it this way:
N mod 16 = X+0.3
N mod 24 = X+0.3
Where N is the number we need to find and X is the integer value of that number (number, for example, X= 76.8, integer value of that would just be 76)

Answer (score 0):

Note $24x+3=16y+3$ let $x=y=0$. Then you get $3=3$. if $x,y>0$ is required, then you have the fact:$$2\cdot24=3\cdot 16=48$$ in which case add 48 to each side of our previous solution, giving $51=51$